# Link to a pdf file works on mobile but not on desktop

Tags: html, hyperlink

Do you have any idea why I have an error 404 on desktop with the following link but it works perfectly on mobile ?

```
<footer><a class="btn" target="_blank" href="CV.pdf">Download Resume</a></footer>
```

Comment: This error can come from several reasons. Did you tried in more browsers on destkop? Do you use a framework? What's in the addressbar when you click on it on the destkop and what in the mobile

Comment: Oh yeah I just checked and it works on every browser except Safari. And no I don't use a framework When the link works on my mobile or chrome for instance, the link is simply like mywebsite.com/CV.pdf However, on Safari it redirects me on the error 404 page of my host which is Awardspace (https://www.awardspace.com/error-404/)